# can not debug .net dump in windbg

Tags: .net, windows, windbg

I got a WER report that our .net application is crashing on some machine, and i got the dump file for the crash, but i tried lots s methods, read many articles about debugging .net crash but still with no luck, i even could not run the extension command of provided by sos.dll, i always got the following message

"Failed to find runtime DLL (clr.dll), 0x80004005
Extension commands need clr.dll in order to have something to do."

i wonder how can i know the .net framework version on that machine? because non extension command could work!! Please help!!

And when i use "lm" command to list all the loaded modules, i did not find "clr" or "clrjit" module in the module list, does this mean that my application actually is not running before it crash, can i say the .net framework on the machine is broken?

(**locationswitch** is my application and it is compiled as x86 application target on .net framework 4.0)

```
0:000> .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll
0:000> .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
0:000> .chain
Extension DLL search Path:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\WINXP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext;C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext\arcade;C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\pri;C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86);C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext\arcade;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
Extension DLL chain:
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll: image 4.0.30319.18444, built Thu Oct 31 05:47:48 2013
        [path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll]
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll: image 4.0.30319.18444, API 1.0.0, built Thu Oct 31 05:40:34 2013
        [path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll]
    dbghelp: image 6.12.0002.633, API 6.1.6, built Tue Feb 02 04:08:26 2010
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 6.12.0002.633, API 1.0.0, built Tue Feb 02 04:08:31 2010
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 6.12.0002.633, API 1.0.0, built Tue Feb 02 04:08:24 2010
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 6.12.0002.633, API 1.0.0, built Tue Feb 02 04:08:23 2010
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 6.1.7650.0, API 1.0.0, built Tue Feb 02 04:08:08 2010
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
0:000> !pe
Failed to find runtime DLL (clr.dll), 0x80004005
Extension commands need clr.dll in order to have something to do.
0:000> lm
start    end        module name
00400000 0040a000   locationswitch   (deferred)
6f720000 6f992000   AcLayers   (deferred)             
705c0000 70616000   mscoree    (deferred)             
70620000 706b9000   apphelp    (deferred)             
70960000 7096d000   sfc_os     (deferred)             
70970000 70973000   sfc        (deferred)             
70eb0000 70ec4000   mpr        (deferred)             
749e0000 74a3e000   winspool   (deferred)             
75560000 755cd000   sysfer     (deferred)             
755d0000 75623000   bcryptPrimitives   (deferred)             
75630000 75639000   CRYPTBASE   (deferred)             
75640000 7565d000   sspicli    (deferred)             
756d0000 7581f000   user32     (deferred)             
75830000 758ff000   KERNELBASE   (pdb symbols)          d:\debug_pdb\wkernelbase.pdb\AD71B4B6970B457EAAC4B4033A1DC8892\wkernelbase.pdb
75980000 759a5000   imm32      (deferred)             
75d30000 75edd000   setupapi   (deferred)             
75ee0000 75f90000   rpcrt4     (deferred)             
76030000 760b7000   oleaut32   (deferred)             
76260000 7629e000   sechost    (deferred)             
762a0000 762e1000   shlwapi    (deferred)             
762f0000 763f7000   gdi32      (deferred)             
76460000 765a0000   kernel32   (deferred)             
765a0000 766ee000   combase    (deferred)             
766f0000 767e7000   msctf      (deferred)             
767f0000 779b0000   shell32    (deferred)             
77a30000 77a6a000   cfgmgr32   (deferred)             
77a80000 77b3e000   msvcrt     (deferred)             
77c10000 77d78000   ntdll      (private pdb symbols)  d:\debug_pdb\wntdll.pdb\080480471A674FFFA11D05343C7475392\wntdll.pdb
```

Comment: @Dono: it is an x86 dump, because it has x86 module addresses. It is x86 WinDbg, because he could load x86 version of SOS. IMHO it's not needed to unload clr (although useless to load), because it does not have valid WinDbg entry points. The output of `lm` is also ok to see that there is no CLR module loaded, also not .NET 2 (assuming we see the full output). So it's quite good what the OP did so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the dump. You assume it to be a .NET 4 dump, but CLR is not loaded. So let's go a few steps back and look from it from a different perspective.

### Precondition checks

It's always good to do some precondition checks before starting with debugging. Let's verify if all your assumptions about the dump are correct. To do that, you should have a rough idea about the dump you are receiving.

Things I always check before doing any analysis:

1. Is it really my application?
2. Is it an official (supported) version or a nightly build?
3. Does it run on a supported OS?
4. Is it the correct type of dump?
5. Is the dump of correct bitness?
6. Did a .NET exception occur? (question for .NET application only, of course)
7. Which version of .NET was loaded? (.NET only)
8. Is it a recent dump?

**Is it really my application?**

Sometimes, customers just send in the wrong dump. Something they find on disk anywhere. 
In case of WER (through the online portal), there are collisions and you might download a wrong dump from Microsoft.

```
|
lm fm MyAppName
```

Check the name of the application and the installation directory. Is the module found? Is the installation directory at least plausible or completely off?

**Is it an official (supported) version?**

```
lm vm MyAppName
```

Check file version and product version against your list of released products.

**Does it run on a supported OS?**

```
vertarget
```

The first line should give the operating system. Note that it will say x86 for 32 bit dumps, even if running on x64.

**Is it the correct type of dump?**

For .NET you need a full memory dump.

```
||
.shell -ci ".dumpdebug" find "MiniDump"
```

The first command should output "Full memory user mini dump", the second should include "0002 MiniDumpWithFullMemory".

*Is the dump of correct bitness?**

Especially for 32 bit applications on 64 bit Windows, this is essential.

```
lm m wow64
```

If the WOW64 module is found, request a new dump.

**Did a .NET exception occur?**

At least we should know what we are after. If it's not .NET, better know that in advance.

```
.exr -1
```

The output should be `e0434f4d (CLR exception)`. Only in some cases .NET will use something else (e.g. `c0000005 (Access violation)` for a `NullReferenceException`).

**Which version of .NET was loaded?**

Especially if you want to reproduce the issue.

```
lm vm clr
lm vm mscorwks
```

Always check for both. It might happen that both versions are loaded (in which case you might be in trouble analyzing the dump).

**Is it a recent dump?**

Did the customer send a new dump or the same crappy dump from last week? Check it, before you lose hours of debugging.

```
.time
```

### Final options

At least one precondition is not met: CLR was not loaded, so it's likely a native exception happening. Start from

```
.exr -1
```

to see what it could be.

It is possible that your application crashed before any .NET was loaded. This can be due to some **hooking DLLs** which are injected into the process.

Maybe it cannot find a **referenced DLL**, because it was not installed, deleted or the program was run from a different working directory.

```
.shell -ci "!peb" find "CurrentDirectory"
```

The dump was taken using [SysInternals ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) with option `-e1` and stoped at the initial breakpoint (which is unexpected for many developers).